# Were there any published details on Heroquesting for Runequest 1-3rd edition?

Tags: runequest

Heroquesting is a process hinted at in the Runequest / Glorantha setting rules since the first edition of the game. Were any rules ever published officially in the first three editions (Chaosium or Avalon Hill era), or for that matter, in an official form for later, but compatible editions? In a couple of the third edition modules (*Haunted Ruins*, *Strangers in Prax*) there are NPCs in the process of Heroquesting, and have some benefits reflected in their character sheets, implying there had been some thought toward defining this process at a later date. A passage in *Sun County* states (page 126):

> Since, at the time of publication, rules governing Heroquesting are not available, [...]

This was published in 1992.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  We're all still waiting.

The new Runequest Glorantha product will (we've been told) include heroquesting rules when the gamemaster's guide is published, but that is still in progress.

In the meantime, many people have been using homegrown rules systems for this.  I recommend [Steve Marsh’s Heroquest rules](https://adrr.com/hero/) for one well-known example.  Or, you can temporarily switch to Hero Wars / Heroquest rules within the confines of the hero plane. That’s another common approach in the Glorantha community. When you return to the normal world the GM will need to improvise benefits and costs.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Be sure to check out the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions.